# Convert two polygons to one

Tags: qgis, shapefile

I use QGIS 2.18.5 and I get in stuck with two polygons I cannot solve.

[image]

I want to make a new polygon from these two which looks like this:
[image]

I made thew new one:

Cut 1 polygon and paste to other layer. Used polygon to lines toolbox then explode lines, then deleted the lines which do not needed then used the add feature to connect lines. Last I dissolve new lines then convert lines to polygons. The new polygon looks like that I wanted to get in QGIS but when I use wayline converter which convert polygons to my tractor GPS it is only shows one polygon:

[image]

What could be the problem?

---

Look I deleted the line I do not need.

[image]

When I select Vertex Tool it appears the line I deleted earlier.

[image]

I think this is the main problem but I do not know how to remote it well..

---

[image]

I found it but is is not the result I wanted to get. :D

Look I want to this from 2 Polygons: I want that new polygons that is circled with red:

[image]

After used the Minimum Bounding as Minimum Oriented Rectangle I got this:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Copy both polygons to the same layer as you did. Than use `Menu Processing / Toolbox / Minimum bounding geometry`. In the dialog, select `Minimum Oriented Rectangle` as geometry type.

*Screenshot: orange - input polygons; blue: result*
[image]

Comment: I am not finding Minimum bounding geometry when I type it to the searching window..  should I need to download some plugins or etc for it?

Comment: Type `hull` in the search window (see screenshot): does that help?

Answer (score 0):

At the beginning, you don't need to toggle edition for cutting one polygon and paste it in another layer for obtained your "circled with red" expected polygon (referred in a deleted answer). You can do that by using available tools in Processing as follows. First, I recreated your two polygons as in following image (I use QGIS 3.18):

[image]

By using Merge tool I got:

[image]

Afterward, I used Minimum Bounding Geometry, with Minimum Oriented Rectangle in Geometry type option, for obtaining result of following image:

[image]

Union of Bounding Geometry with pol1 (in your case 0487-24) as Overlay layer produces result as follows.

[image]

In Union layer you can delete the upper and null produced features to get expected polygon. It could also be necessary to edit layer for deleting some unwanted points. Result looks as follows:

[image]

Comment: Xunilk!! It is almost what I wanted to get :) Only one thing is not working on me the Minimum Oriented Rectangle. Look what I got after processing.. I added the screenschot at the end of the original question because I can not add here. sorry